# PDF/A 3 using Apache PDFBox

Tags: pdfa

What metadatas I need to set to create a big PDF/A 3 archiving documents? Right now I am using PDF Box as it is open source. Also I am not sure how to validate created PDF document, whether it is valid or not and meets all standard or not. I used online link: https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx to validate document.

Is it possible to validate PDF/A-3 document through any open source API?

Comment: Go through Documentation [How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a query

Comment: You can validate PDF/A-3 with http://verapdf.org/ . Re the metadata, buy the PDF/A-3 specification (you have to pay for it), or use the CreatePDFA.java code from the source code download (or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreatePDFA.java?view=markup ), and replace `id.setPart(1)` with `id.setPart(3)`. Does this help as an answer or do you need more?

Comment: is Metadata in the class you have provided enough or there is more that I need to do to make it PDF/A-3 compliance?

Comment: Also is it required to buy PDF/A-3 specification to create document? Can I not generate PDF/A doc without purchasing it?

Comment: No you don't have to buy the PDF/A-3 specification to create the document. I modified the sample code last month and was able to create a PDF/A-3b document, i.e. PDF-Tools said it was correct. Without knowing the specification, it will be a lot of guessing and trial & error.